# Passing Date Field to a Javascript Function

Tags: apex, javascript, datetime, parameters

I am trying to pass a datetime field to a Javascript function:

```
onclick="myfunction('{!c.ID}', 
                    '{!c.Start_Date__c}', 
                    '{!c.Reason__c}');"
```

This passes the default formatted Apex datetime which looks like this:
MON Jan 01 14:00:00 GMT 2018

Javascript does not parse this as a date.  So I need something formatted in a way that JS recognizes as a date (unless I want to parse it myself).

I have tried:

```
onclick="myfunction('{!c.ID}', 
                    '{!(c.Start_Date__c).format()}', 
                    '{!c.Reason__c}');"
```

But that doesn't work.  I have also tried added parentheses:

```
 '{!((c.Start_Date__c).format())}',
```

No luck with that either.  I am trying to avoid having to parse the string myself in JS.  Any suggestions?

Comment: See if this helps: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/89816/what-is-the-correct-way-to-send-an-apex-type-containing-datetime-members-to-remo/91503#91503

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parse the date yourself; JavaScript will do it for you if you use the new Date constructor.

```
onclick="myfunction('{!c.ID}', new Date('{!c.Start_Date__c}'),  '{!c.Reason__c}');"
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  I get a syntax error:  "Syntax error.  Missing '}'".  It's basically the same as the second option in my explanation, except your are doing the conversion in the call rather than the JS.  It's the {!(c.Start_Date__c).format()} that is causing the problem.  That's clearly not the correct syntax and I don't know what is.

Comment: @SalesForceJedi Sorry, I got a bit copy-paste-happy. Try this new and improved version.